# Spectral sequences of bicomplexes: are differentials chain complex maps?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, spectral-sequences

This is a probably stupid question, and I guess the answer is no, but it's worth trying.
Consider the spectral sequence $E^{pq}_r$ associated to a bicomplex (of abelian groups). At page $r$ we will have several parallel complex with differentials $\delta_r$. Is it possible to define $\tilde{\delta}_{r+1}$ at page $r$ as so that it defines maps of $\delta_r$-chain complexes? We also ask that $\tilde{\delta}_{r+1}$ induces $\delta_{r+1}$ in homology.

If this is true, what if we start with a multicomplex?

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. If you don't mind copying it to the answer section, I will accept it. I'd be quite happy to know also when there is such an extension in terms of explicit groups (like Ext and homology of internal hom), but it's not required. For example, I have the impression that maps giving a fixed morphism in homology (if there are any) are parametrized by null-homotopic maps plus some Ext groups. Existence of one lift should be doable in terms of Ext groups too.